# How to use Flink with Kafka 0.10.1.0?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Does Flink support Kafka 0.10.1.0?

I saw there is a `flink-connector-kafka-0.10` but i am not able to see it in flink latest version.

currently I am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The next minor version of Flink, Flink 1.2.0, will include a connector for Kafka 0.10.x  (see [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-4035)).

The feature freeze for 1.2.0 happened a few days ago. Flink 1.2.0 will be released after testing and community vote, hopefully in January 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am running Flink 1.1.4 with Kafka 0.10.0.0 using the Kafka Connector 0.9_2.10

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```